# How does Celery Chord works in Python?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have the following piece of code:

```
def create_pipeline(
    real: DataFrame,
    forecast_name: str,
    energy_asset_id: int,
    family: str,
    forecast_range: date_range,
    methodologies: List[str],
    start_forecast: datetime,
    subfamily_x_forecast_id: int,
    uuid: str,
    subfamily_id: int,
    execution_id: int,
) -> None:
    forecast_tasks = []
    for methodology in methodologies:
        log.info(f"Methodology: {methodology}")
        forecast_task = celery_app.signature(
            PATHS.get(methodology.lower(), "app.worker.classic.forecast"),
            args=[
                real,
                forecast_name,
                energy_asset_id,
                family,
                methodology,
                forecast_range,
                start_forecast,
                uuid,
                subfamily_id,
            ],
        )
        forecast_tasks.append(forecast_task)

    combination_task = celery_app.signature(
        "app.worker.combinations.pipeline_combinations",
        args=[
            energy_asset_id,
            family,
            methodologies,
            forecast_name,
            subfamily_x_forecast_id,
            uuid,
            start_forecast,
            execution_id,
        ],
        queue=f"combinations-{settings.ENV}"
    )
    group_forecast_task = chord(forecast_tasks)
    group_forecast_task(combination_task)
```

In total there are 8 methodologies so forecast_tasks is a list with 8 tasks.
What I need is for these 8 tasks to be executed and once the 8 tasks have finished, the combination_task task is executed (adding the result of group_forecast_task as the first argument), for that I implement the part of:

```
group_forecast_task = chord(forecast_tasks)
group_forecast_task(combination_task)
```

I had implemented it like this in another project recently but now it doesn't work for me! The 8 forecast tasks are executed but when they finish, combination_task is never called, what could be happening? I'm not really sure how chord actually works and if I'm implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you did not mention any exception being thrown by workers I assume everything "works" as expected.

With the abovementioned asumption, here is my first guess - you do not have workers subscribed to the `combinations-{settings.ENV}` queue, so there is no worker to run that task. This is a very common mistake.

I typically pass queues in the CLI when I start workers, something like: `celery -A my.app worker -Q queueA,queueB -O fair ...etc`

Make sure you have `-Q combinations-{settings.ENV}` (replace {settings.ENV} with the actually name of the environment). If you send tasks to the default queue and expect this worker to pick them up and execute, then you need to explicitly add `celery` to the list of queues, it would become `-Q combinations-{settings.ENV},celery` in this particular case (beginners often make this mistake as well).